# flash.message does not print message on the screen in grails 2.x

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-2.2, grails-2.1

My functionality is I have a list of users. When I click on any of the users to edit his information a new window pop up.
I change some values and click on save. Now values are saved correctly but 'saved successfully' message is not displayed.

My controller code is

```
if(user.save(flush:true)){
    user.messages = "${message(code: 'user.saved')}"
    flash.userInstance = user
    render ...
}
```

and in gsp I print message like this

```
 <div id="messages">
        <g:if test="${userInstance?.messages}">
            <div class="message">${userInstance?.messages}</div>
        </g:if>
<div>
```

Here Call does not go inside g:if condition hence message is not printed.
This was working well in grails 1.3 but fails in 2.2. Why is that so?

Comment: Have you tried `<g:if test="${flash.userInstance?.messages}">`?

Comment: yes I tried that but flash.userInstance is null

Comment: hmmm put a println before `flash.userInstance = user`. Your flow printed the user?

Comment: Are you sending Ajax request?

Comment: No it is not ajax request

Comment: If all your displaying is a message, you're solution is overkill.  Just do flash.message "${message(code: 'user.saved')}".  I'm not even sure flash scope supports complex objects.  I'll go find out...

Comment: Ok, looks like flash scope *should* support it.  But I still say you're complicating matters. :)

Answer (score 1):

This example works for me. Maybe you have some validation errors, try to debug your code.

```
if(user.save(flush:true)){
        user.messages = "${message(code: 'user.saved')}"
        flash.userInstance = user
        render ...
}
```

and in gsp

```
<div id="messages">
   <g:if test="${flash?.userInstance?.messages}">
       <div class="message">${flash?.userInstance?.messages}</div>
   </g:if>
<div>
```